# Plotting Fiscal Period Time Series Data in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot fiscal period (monthly) time series data in R.

My data is given by fiscal period, and is labeled "P2 2016" etc.

I do not know how to convert this to a date format effectively as it contains a period (not a default date format in R) and a year in the same date string.

If anyone has any experience with this problem I would really appreciate your input.

Comment: There are asked and answered SO questions on using Dates and yearmon classes for fiscal quarters. You should a) do some searching and then if still without illumination ... b)post some data and say what the right answer would be. If you do post data and specific request, I will reverese my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

Without any data and an exact question, I can't provide much help. But, the code below will at least split your labels into a period and year. You'll probably want to store the output from `strsplit` in a new variable so you can then store the outputs in a dataframe.

```
foo <- c("P2 2016")
foo

strsplit(gsub("P", "", foo), " ")
```